# Why ViewPart can't implements an interface from another Project?

Tags: java, eclipse, implements

Currently, I created a plug-in using available Templates (Plug-in with a view) in eclipse. The plug-in is still OK until I tried implementing an interface FROM ANOTHER PROJECT (It's still ok if this interface was created in Plug-in project). The first thing I thought is a class maybe can't implement an interface from another project but When I tried creating a normal class then implement above interface it's ok. So why ViewPart can't implement above interface? Thank you.

```
public class SampleView extends ViewPart implements Iface {

    @Override
    public void updateFace(){

    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had it right there in the question: "It's still ok if this interface was created in Plug-in project". **Everything** at **runtime** has to come from a plug-in you declare as a dependency somehow, including other classes and interfaces you want to refer to. Otherwise the runtime literally doesn't know where to look for those class files. You can make the other project a plug-in itself, or package it as a jar and include it in your existing plug-in by adding it to the **Classpath** section of the **Runtime** tab in the **Plug-in Manifest Editor**.

Comment: I tried your solution by exporting the project including the interface to jar file then add it to existing plug-in project. But my plug-in is still unable to run. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "is still unable to run"? Does it not launch? If it does, what error message are you encountering? Or does this merit a separate Question?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upload image so I post image link here https://s12.postimg.org/d7pjqk4ct/Untitled.png

Comment: You'll want to look at the entire contents of the dialog. There might be additional traces digging into the reasons behind *why* it couldn't load the class.

Comment: @DucTran Copy the **whole** text of the stack trace in to your question as text - not an image.

Comment: And then look up in the JavaDoc what those particular Errors and Exceptions mean.

Comment: [link](https://s16.postimg.org/fqfxfxeqd/Untitled.png) I think the problems is here. But I still can't find any solution.

Comment: @DucTran So the `bag.Iface` class cannot be found - where is this class? Is it in a plugin? Does the plugin export that package? Is the plugin a dependency of the plugin containing the view?

Comment: @greg-449 It's in the jar file that I add into the plug-in project. But I dont understand why it cannot be found in run time

Comment: What's it path within that jar file? And you did add the jar file to the classpath section?

Comment: @DucTran As the answer already says you must add all jars in a plugin to the Classpath in the MANIFEST.MF/plugin.xml editor - do not just update the Java Build Path. You must also include the jars in the build.properties.

Comment: I finally got the solution. In MANIFES.MF file add " Bundle-ClassPath: .,interfaceproject.jar " and the Plug-in can find that jar file in runtime. Thank you for your help guys